# Parsing a massive .dat file in Python and doing an arithmetic operation

Tags: python, parsing

I'm new to Python and relatively new to programming in general.  My basic problem is to parse through a large data file (several million rows of data), stored in a dat file.

Sample data from the file is:

```
820401001 825029767710821718 8 5 510-180090000 8   9   4
820401001 8083 7970200661367 7 8 0 3-170090070 0  24   1
820401001 8082 4745200341-18 4 9 0 3 240080044 0 -20   2
820401001 8062 5805200461367 2 9 0 3 120066725 0  -7   2
820401001 8037 5292200491-17 7 7 0 3-170090070 0 -16   2
```

I know the following information:

- The length of each row is always 56 characters.  All characters are either a digit or the "-" sign.  Essentially, the data is numerical.
- There are 20 columns to each row, and the columns widths (ie num of characters) are 8, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4

In addition to parsing each line, I need to perform an arithmetic operation on columns 3 and 4.  Specifically, I want to take the 5 characters and divide by 100, eg instead of 29767 I want 297.67

The objective is to create a massive matrix with the resulting values.  Ideally, I'd like to save the matrix in a new file, but I'm unsure how to do that.

The desired output would be something like:

```
82040100 1 82.50 297.67 71082 1 71 8 8 5 5 10 -1 800 900 0 0 8 9 4
82040100 1 80.83  79.70 20066 1 36 7 7 8 0  3 -1 700 900 7 0 0 24 1
```

I am aware that I can use the struct library (see code attempt below) but I obtain the error "unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 224 bytes".  I have absolutely no idea what that means.

In addition, I don't know how to perform the operation on columns 3 and 4 in an efficient manner, ie can I do it at the same time when parsing, or do add a separate "if-else" statement?

```
import struct

fieldwidths = (8, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4) 
fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'i') for fw in fieldwidths)
fieldstruct = struct.Struct(fmtstring)

parse = fieldstruct.unpack_from
print('fmtstring: {!r}, recsize: {} chars'.format(fmtstring, fieldstruct.size))

print("Opening the file.")
data_file = open("APR82L.dat", "r")

print("\nReading one line at a time")
#set to 10 just to test
for i in range(10):
    line = data_file.readline()
    print(line)
    fields = parse(line)
    print('fields: {}'.format(fields))

#Close the data file
print("\nClosing the data file")
data_file.close
```

Comment: Is your data stored in binary format or ascii?  For example, how did you look at that sample data that you show?  (Because of the odd spacing you show, I'm assuming ascii, but want to verify before writing an answer.)

Comment: The key question: do you need it to be **fast**? In other words, will the script be run: just once? every month? every 10 seconds?

Comment: `struct.unpack` is for decoding binary data not for splitting strings.

Comment: In Python you need to add parentheses in order to call a method: `data_file.close()`

Comment: I've shown the data exactly as I've viewed it in Sublime.  The solution does need to fast - this will be run daily, several times a day.

Answer (score 3):

Your format string consists of 56 int fields, which are each assumed to be four bytes long: thus to unpack a string, the string must be at least `4*56 = 224` bytes long. However, you're passing in strings of length 56 (-ish, depending on line endings).

You could presumably massage your data into a format suitable for passing to `struct.unpack_from`, but the real issue is that `struct` is intended to pack/unpack binary data, not text strings. You might end up spending more time preparing the input than you would actually parsing it. There's a fair chance that you'll find it easier to avoid dealing with `struct` altogether, and just write a simple line parser yourself, something like this:

```
col_widths = [8, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4]

def parse(line): # this is neither blazing fast, nor clever, but it does work.
    fields = []
    idx = 0
    for width in col_widths:
        next_idx = idx + width
        fields.append(int(line[idx:next_idx]))
        idx = next_idx
    return fields
```

In addition, you may want to use a simple check to ensure that each line is even worth parsing:

```
with open('APR82L.dat') as data_file:
    for line in data_file: # This is the normal way to read a file line by line
        if line.strip(): # if the line isn't empty:
            fields = parse(line)
```

---

As for performing arithmetic, do it whenever it makes sense to do so. If it's a relatively simple operation, I'd suggest writing a function to do whatever needs doing, and calling that function as you read the data.

```
def calculate(fields):
    x = fields[2] # third field
    y = fields[3] # fourth field
    return x + y # or whatever

with open('APR82L.dat') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        # parse line into fields as above, then:

        result = calculate(fields)
        # then write the result someplace or whatever's appropriate
```

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy library](http://www.numpy.org/) is designed to do just this, if you don't mind a relatively light-weight dependency that most folks oriented towards scientific computing will already have installed.

Step 1:

Parse fixed width format to comma or space separated with cut, awk and/or sed.

Step 2:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('parsed.txt')
```

Adding columns 2 and 3 would then be as simple as

```
output = data[:,2] + data[:,3]
```

Alternatively, you could use the function [fromregex](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html) do the parsing and numpy arraying in one step.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you have an ascii data table, and for this, a good tool to start with is Python's built in string manipulation (see bottom for more).  Also, your data isn't that "massive", so you should start by writing the code so it's easy, and then optimize later if you need to.

Here's a little Python program that does the parsing, hopefully self-explanatory.  I start with a string to define the structure, which I just made up as an easy way to define it.

```
structure = "8i 1i 5f 5f 5i 1i 2i 1i 2i 2i 2i 2i 2i 3i 3i 1i 1i 2i 4i 4i"
structure = structure.split()

result = []
with open("data.txt") as df:
    for line in df.readlines():
        n, vals = 0, []
        for s in structure:
            width = int(s[0])
            val = int(line[n:n+width])
            if s[1]=='f':
                val = val/100.
            vals.append(val)
            n += width
        result.append(vals)
```

This gives:

```
result = [
[82040100, 1, 82.5, 297.67, 71082, 1, 71, 8, 8, 5, 5, 10, -1, 800, 900, 0, 0, 8, 9, 4]
[82040100, 1, 80.83, 79.7, 20066, 1, 36, 7, 7, 8, 0, 3, -1, 700, 900, 7, 0, 0, 24, 1]
[82040100, 1, 80.82, 47.45, 20034, 1, -1, 8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 2, 400, 800, 4, 4, 0, -20, 2]
[82040100, 1, 80.62, 58.05, 20046, 1, 36, 7, 2, 9, 0, 3, 1, 200, 667, 2, 5, 0, -7, 2]
[82040100, 1, 80.37, 52.92, 20049, 1, -1, 7, 7, 7, 0, 3, -1, 700, 900, 7, 0, 0, -16, 2]]
```

`struct` is mostly for parsing binary data, so although you could use it, it's not the best choice.  Also, numpy's loadtxt needs some type delimitter, which you don't have so that won't work either (unless you pre-parse the data, which seems to defeat the point).

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple string treatment. Here is a example parser that should do what you want :

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, fd):
        self.widths = (8, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                       3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4)
        self.seps = '  . .                \n'
        self.fd = fd
    def parse(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
            for line in file:
                l = []
                ix = 0
                out = ''
                rank=0
                for j in self.widths:
                    l.append(line[ix:ix+j])
                    out = out + str(int(line[ix:ix+j])) + self.seps[rank]
                    rank += 1
                    ix += j
                self.fd.write(out)
```

You create the parser with a file object (such as sys.stdout) as parameter. This file object will receive the output and you call parse with the input filename as parameter :

```
import sys
parser = Parser(sys.stdout)
parser.parse('input.dat')
```

If you want to write on another file :

```
with open('outfile.dat', 'w') ad fd:
    parser = Parser(fd)
    parser.parse('input.dat')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little note: If you have GNU awk (which you will if you're using a GNU/linux distro), you can do this transformation really easily from the bash prompt

```
awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="8 1 5 5 5 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 4 4" \
    '{$3/=100;$4/=100;print}' \
    < input.dat > newfile.dat
```

If you wanted to separate the fields with tab characters in the output, add `-vOFS='\t'` before the `-vFIELDWIDTHS=...` assignment.